# Two lists with a relationship, how to display them to the user?

Tags: c#

My problem is that I want to make a program that uses two lists, which is almost impossible for me to understand. Okay, so the deal is that I want to make a program where you first type in a city name and then the temperature for the city. This is where the relationship comes from.

I have started by making a "list class", which looks like this:

```
class citytemp
{
    private string city;
    private double temp;

    public citytemp(string city, double temp)
    {
        this.city = city;
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    public string City
    {
        get { return city; }
        set { city = value; }
    }

    public double Temp
    {
        get { return temp; }
        set { temp = value; }
    }
}
```

Then I make the list in the program like this

```
List<citytemp> temps = new List<citytemp>();
```

Which all looks good to me. But when I'm trying to show the user the list nothing shows up. I use these lines to show it:

```
for (int i = 0; i > temps.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(temps[i].City, temps[i].Temp);
}
```

BTW: I add "things" to the list by these rows:

```
temps.Add(new citytemp(tempcity, temptemp));
```

...where `tempcity` and `temptemp` are temporary variables. They are only there to make it more simple for me to add them to the list, since I'm using a `switch` statement to add them to the list.

To make things more clear, my problem is that I don't know how I'm suppose to show the list to the user in the program.

Comment: Feel kind of stupid now -.-", but thanks to all of you for helping me out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the for loop. Change it to this

```
for (int i = 0; i < temps.Count; i++)
```

i.e. change the greater than `>` operator to a less than `<`

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i > temps.Count; i++)
```

it should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < temps.Count; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm not sure what you mean by "2 lists" as you only have one list in your code.

However, the problem you're having with "nothing shows up" is easy to fix.

This line of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i > temps.Count; i++)
```

Should be read as follows:

```
i = 0;
while (i > temps.Count)
{
    ... rest of your loop body here

    i++;
}
```

if you read this, you'll notice that the second part of the `for` statement is not *when to terminate* but *how long to keep going*.

Change it to this, and you should be good:

```
for (int i = 0; i < temps.Count; i++)
                  ^
                  +-- changed from >
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a hashtable, specifically a dictionary would help you here:

```
var cityTemps = new Dictionary<string, double>();
cityTemps.Add("TestCity", 56.4);

foreach (var kvp in cityTemps)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
```

Comment: What if Adam want's to add more fields to the class (e.g. population)? A short sighted solution.

Comment: A more efficient solution given the current operating contraints.  If more fields existed, and the question specifically didn't say: "I want to make a program that uses two lists", then my response would have been different.  I just saw an opportunity to present the OP with a technique he may not have run into before.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the loop that has been mentioned, be careful with`Console.WriteLine` because it takes in a `String` as first argument which it assumes is a format and `object[] params` as a second parameter. When you pass `temps[i].City` to it since its `String` it will think that its the format and `temps[i].Temp` is the parameter and won't display correctly.

What you want instead:

```
Console.WriteLine("City: {0} Temp: {1}", temps[i].City, temps[i].Temp);
```

Here I am using `"City: {0} Temp: {1}"` as the format for the string and the proper parameters.

This answer is to save you a headache later on wondering why only the city name is being displayed.